# How to get var value from another .js file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

In my first .js file I have a global var with name `workitemInspectorValue`.

How will I get the value of `workitemInspectorValue` with jQuery from the second .js file?

Comment: You shouldn't use global variable, they can easily break your code. However, since it's globale, you should probably have access to it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery. In JavaScript global variables are visible to all included files that are run after the definition. If you included the files in the correct order, you should be able to see and use the global var.

Aside from that, consider scoping your variables. For example, pass them as function parameters or if you really need, attach them to ONE global object or the DOM (e.g. as attribute to `document`). A common approach is also storing data at the objects in question on the DOM. Consider the [data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) technique, which is a standard and well supported by jQuery.